# Почему обращение к SomeClass.class не вызывает инициализацию класса SomeClass?

Tags: java, rtti

*Вопрос такой*: Почему использование A.class не вызывает инициализацию класса А?

Хотя, учитывая, что подготовка класса к использованию состоит из трёх этапов, на первом из которых создаётся объект Class, и лишь третий из которых -- непосредственная инициализация, **вопрос логичнее поставить так**:
Почему вызов `Class.forName("test.A");` провоцирует инициализацию класса А?
 Может сам метод `Class.forName(String)` создан так, чтобы целиком насильно загружать классы?

```
package test;

class A {
    static {
        System.out.println("A is initialized");
    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class c = A.class;
        System.out.println("whoa...");
        c = Class.forName("test.A");
    }
}
```

---

```
Expected output:
    A is initialized
    whoa...

Real output:
    whoa...
    A is initialized
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [JLS 12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) написано:

> Invocation of certain reflective methods in class Class and in package java.lang.reflect also causes class or interface initialization.

Что в переводе:

> **Вызов некоторых** отражающих **методов в классе Class** и в пакете java.lang.reflect также **вызывает инициализацию класса** или интерфейса.

А в [этой](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) документации для метода forName() класса Class чётко написано:

> A call to forName("X") causes the class named X to be initialized.

Что в переводе:

> Вызов forName («X») вызывает инициализацию класса с именем X.

**Соответственно**, всё оказалось верно! Метод `Class.forName(String)` действительно насильно загрузит класс.

Answer (score 4):

В [JLS 12.4.1](http://JLS%2012.4.1.) написано, что статическая инициализация происходит перед:

- Созданием экземпляра класса;
- Вызовом статического метода класса;
- Присвоением статического поля класса;
- Использованием неконстантного статического поля класса;
- Выполнением оператора `assert` в классах верхнего уровня.

А при вызове метода `forName()` ClassLoader осуществляет принудительную инициализацию.